# Websphere CE (Community Edition) fails to load properties from file to InitialContext

Tags: migration, websphere-ce

my web app works good on tomcat server, now i am porting it to Websphere CE,

app reads properties file & load it to IntialContext, if I run the app using

- tomcat >> InitialContext ic has env variable and properties are loaded in env

but in

- Websphere CE >> InitialContext ic has env variable and  env is empty

and app is failing?

just to add
in both cases (running on tomcat or websphere CE), InitialContext has variable myProp which has all properties from the file... which means properties file was read ..

I have properties file in classes dir and call a service from third party jar file, using debugger & decompiler I could found above difference, but now stuck here?

can you please share tips/suggestions in this case?

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by adding jboss jars (used for NJDI) in endorsed directory of WAS-CE.

But now facing SocketTimeout while getting remote object.

How/where can we set sockettimeout property of WAS-CE ?